# Quotient of finitely presented group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose $G, H$ be two groups such that $G$ is finitely presented(with number of defining relators must be at least 1) and let $\phi$ : $G \rightarrow$ $H$ be an epimorphism. Does it imply that $H$ a finitely presented group?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? Does the requirement about the number of relators really matter at all?

Comment: I thought, if this result were true for empty defining relator, then suppose $K$ is a group which is finitely generated but not finitely presented since $K$ is the homomorphic image of some free group which will imply that $K$ is finitely presented.

Comment: Your observation, that every finitely generated group is an epimorphic image of a finitely generated free group, almost solves the problem. The only remaining difficulty is that you want at east one relator, and the usual presentation of a free group has no relators. To get around that problem, modify the usual presentation of a free group by putting in one more generator and putting in a relation saying that the new generator equals the identity. (If that new relator looks unpleasantly trivial, then change it to say that the new generator equals some messy word built from the old generators.)

Comment: Correct!, but in general Can be put some condition on $G$ or may be on $\phi$ in order to guarantee that $H$ is finitely presented?

Comment: $H$ is finitely presented iff the kernel of $G\to H$ is finitely generated as a normal subgroup.

Comment: in that case, can be say that number of defining relators of $H$ are less than of $G$

Answer (score 1):

A method for constructing an example which shows that the answer is negative (see for instance [this reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=QLiOsUrzricC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=image%20of%20a%20finitely%20presented%20group%20not%20finitely%20presented&source=bl&ots=W05M_ziH36&sig=g32S4CHrQXh9emmsUHWfqoFzs_Q&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=image%20of%20a%20finitely%20presented%20group%20not%20finitely%20presented&f=false)) is to go for a finitely presented group $G$ whose centre $Z(G)$ is not finitely generated. Then, by a standard result (which I think has been recorded by Bernhard Neumann), $G/Z(G)$ is not finitely presented.